# How to insert a file into the database in java using servlet and jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

*How to insert a file into the databe using servlet and jsp 
Help me to insert file into DB*

### 1. Servlet File

> ```
>     package FileUpload;
>
>     import java.io.IOException;
>     import java.io.InputStream;
>     import java.sql.Connection;
>     import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
>     import java.sql.SQLException;
>
>     import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
>     import javax.servlet.ServletException;
>     import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
>     import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
>     import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
>     import javax.servlet.http.Part;
>
>     public class UploadImage extends HttpServlet {
>       @Override
>       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
>               throws ServletException, IOException {
>
>           RequestDispatcher rd=req.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/upload.jsp");
>           rd.forward(req, resp);
>       }
>       @Override
>       protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
>               throws ServletException, IOException {
>
>           String name=req.getParameter("name");
>
>           InputStream in=null;
>           Part filePart=req.getPart("photo");
>           if(filePart!=null){
>               System.out.println(filePart.getName());
>                 System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
>                 System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());
>                 in=filePart.getInputStream();
>
>           }
>           ConnectionUtil cu=new ConnectionUtil();
>           Connection conn =cu.getConnection();
>
>           String sql = "insert into upload(name,photo)values(?, ?)";
>           try {
>               PreparedStatement pt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
>                   pt.setString(1,name);
>                   pt.setBlob(2,in);               
>
>               int row = pt.executeUpdate();
>                 if (row > 0) {
>                     req.setAttribute("message", "File uploaded and saved into database");
>                 }
>               RequestDispatcher rd=req.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/upload.jsp");
>               rd.forward(req, resp);  
>           } catch (SQLException e) {
>               e.printStackTrace();
>           }       
>       }
>     }
> ```

---

### 2. jsp file

> ```
>         <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
>     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
> <html>
> <head>
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
> <title>Insert title here</title>
> </head>
> <body>
> <form action="/ram_jsp/upload" method="post">
> <table>
> <tr><td>${message}</td></tr>
> <tr><td>Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
> <tr><td>Choose File:</td><td><input type="file" name="photo" size="100"></td></tr>
> <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Upload">
> </table>
> </form>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

**I'm gettting null value at 'filePart', how to get a file value from jsp to insert into database**

Comment: The `form` should have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)